# Webpack resolve.alias does not work with VS Code IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, visual-studio-code

I wanted my project to include Webpack resolve.alias options, so I added it to my webpack.common.js configuration file.

I had a lot of problems at first, but after searching the web and many GitHub Issues I found some posts which helped me with my problems.

The imports so work, but my problem is Visual Studios IntelliSense is not working with my declared aliasses. My setup:

**My project directory:**

```
+src
  -first
  -second
  +third
  | -third-one
  | -third-two
  | +third-three
  |   -third-three-one
  -jsconfig.json
  -.babelrc
-.eslintrc
-webpack.common.js
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
...
resolve: {
    ...
    alias: {
      first: path.resolve(__dirname, './first'),
      second: path.resolve(__dirname, './second'),
      third: path.resolve(__dirname, './third'),
      common: path.resolve(__dirname, './third/third-three/third-three-one'),
    },
  },
...
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "airbnb"],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "first": "./first",
        "second": "./second",
        "third": "./third",
        "common": "./third/third-three/third-three-one"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

**jsconfig.json**

```
...
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "first": ["./first"],
      "second": ["./second"],
      "third": ["./third"],
      "common": ["./third/third-three/third-three-one"],
    }
},
...
```

**.eslintrc**

```
...
"settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "webpack": {
                "config": "webpack.common.js"
      },
      "babel-module": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
      }
    }
  },
...
```

My for this case important installed npm modules:

```
"webpack": "^2.6.1",
"eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^4.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
"babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.0.0",
```

VS Code: 1.20

Windows 10

**Does anyone know what is missing? Why is IntelliSense not triggering?**

Comment: did you prevail?

Comment: could you explain what you mean?

Comment: Put your jsconfig.json in the root directory or specify baseUrl as '.././'.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the jsconfig to this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "first/*": ["./first/*"],
      "second/*": ["./second/*"],
      "third/*": ["./third/*"],
      "common/*": ["./third/third-three/third-three-one/*"],
    }
}
```

I don't know why exactly, but without the star it wasn't working for me.

Comment: appreciate the answer, but that did not do the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was ensuring that my `baseUrl` was correct as well as my paths, I was using `./` for the root of my project, but then incorrectly specifying my javascript folder (this is a rails project) as `./javascript/some_module` instead of `./app/javascript/some_module`.

Also, ensure you're using the exclude option just to avoid referencing `node_modules`:

```
"exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "public", "public/packs"]
```